# Creating a realtime favorites collection in cloudfirestore using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The thing that i want to do is that i have a bookmark button that creates a Favorites collection for every user, but the data inside it consists of data grabbed from profiles of other users, so I want if the data of the bookmarked profile is edited to appear edited in the favorites list. how to achieve so????

Comment: You can achieve so by storing reference in your cloudfirestore and manage it appropriately in the code. So basically you will be storing document references in your favorites to the user profiles or the data that you want and on the flutter code side get the DocumentReference and use it appropriately. Please let me know if this helps, if you want I can share some code snippets.

Comment: @ssiddh can share some code please??

Comment: @ssiddh basically I am streaming the favorites documents into a listview , so can I use reference 5o complete my list view??

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, here is the link to my repo https://github.com/sudhanshu-15/sunapsisConference2018Flutter
If you look at `models/conference_event` you will see there is a list of presenters which is storing DocumentReference, I am using these DocumentReference in my `EventCard` widget with help of `EventPresenterChipList`. You can check out the implementation, once I have some spare time I will write some detailed explanation.

Comment: @ssiddh ok will read the repo and wait for your explanation